# Problemas Al redireccionar pagina con angularjs en IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

Tengo el siguiente script para poder redireccionar a la pagina que deseo

```
if (!window.location.origin) {
    window.location.origin = window.location.protocol + "//" 
        + window.location.hostname 
        + (window.location.port ? ':' + window.location.port : '');

      $location.$$urlUpdatedByLocation = true; 
      $location.$$absUrl = window.location.origin+location.pathname+"busqTerceros.html";

}else{
    $location.$$urlUpdatedByLocation = true;
    $location.$$absUrl = location.origin+location.pathname+"busqTerceros.html";
}
```

En mi caso tengo problemas al redireccionar con IE(Internet Explorer), el path que estoy utilizando es `window.location.origin+location.pathname+"busqTerceros.html"`

Es raro por que si en la ruta solo dejo `window.location.origin+location.pathname` me lleva a una ruta sin generar un loop que seria una ruta parecida a esto `https://localhost:8080/algo/`

Pero si le agrego la concatenación `+"busqTerceros.html"` se genera un loop infinito.

---

En el archivo busqTerceros.html tengo lo siguiente:

```
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/algo/#!/algo" />
```

**PD: por cierto entra en el IF cuando es internet explorer por que de principio no me reconocía el location.origin por eso lo tuve que crear así.**

Comment: si haces un href y simulas el click no es mejor?

Comment: lo hice con href y con otros redireccionamientos pero el resultado siempre es el mimo un loop infinito.

Comment: pienso que el error no está en el código, mas bien debe estar en el archivo `busqTerceros.html`. Por lo que estuve leyendo en internet la _URL_ tiene que ser absoluta, puede que eso sea lo que este causando el loop.

Comment: Tiene que ser por que el doble redireccionamiento que estoy haciendo de alguna manera esta afectando en que IE se comporte de esta forma, y la única solución que veo por el momento es ocupar route de angularJs, aun no pruebo lo de la ruta absoluta te comentare esto en breve..